# Print parts of bibliography using BibTeX?

Tags: latex, bibliography, biblatex

For some days I am trying to solve the following problem for which I wasn't able to find a solution. Help is very much appreciated.

I am writing a long document and for some sections I would like to print a subset of items from the total bibliography that will be included at the very end before the appendix.

Is there a way do this? I was playing with refsection and imagining something like:

```
 \documentclass[ twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,
            headinclude,footinclude,
            cleardoublepage=empty,abstract=on,
            BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt
            ]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource[label=ownpubs]{ownpubs.bib}
\addbibresource[label=refs]{references.bib}

\begin{document}

%here I want to print a selection of the complete bibliography
%References are required to be consistent throughout the whole document
\chapter*{Related Publications}
\begin{refsection}[references.bib]
    \nocite{*} 
    \printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{refsection}

%here goes all the other stuff: chapters, sections, whatever

%print complete bibliography
\nocite{*} 
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

ownpubs.bib:

```
@article{einstein1935can,
  title={Can quantum-mechanical description of physical reality be considered complete?},
  author={Einstein, Albert and Podolsky, Boris and Rosen, Nathan},
  journal={Physical review},
  volume={47},
  number={10},
  pages={777},
  year={1935},
  publisher={APS}
}
@article{einstein1905movement,
  title={On the movement of small particles suspended in stationary liquids required by the molecularkinetic theory of heat},
  author={Einstein, A},
  journal={Ann. d. Phys},
  volume={17},
  number={549-560},
  pages={1},
  year={1905}
}
```

references.bib:

```
@article{schrodinger1935gegenwartige,
  title={Die gegenw{\"a}rtige Situation in der Quantenmechanik},
  author={Schr{\"o}dinger, Erwin},
  journal={Naturwissenschaften},
  volume={23},
  number={50},
  pages={844--849},
  year={1935},
  publisher={Springer-Verlag}
}
```

With the above code I got the bibliographies printed, but the references (numbers) are not consistent.

Does anyone know a way to approach this problem? I am in no means restricted to splitting the files up. That was just the only solution I was able to come up with.

Thanks for your help and warm Greetings!

Comment: Please make your code compilable. You are using commands from the biblatex package, but don't load it. Furthermore, we don't have the necessary bib file to compile your code.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I updated to a working example that compiles for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a similar approach as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/166018 and automatically add some keyword to all entries in `references.bib`. This will allow you to filter for those when using `\printbibliography`:

```
 \documentclass[ twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,
            headinclude,footinclude,
            cleardoublepage=empty,abstract=on,
            BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt
            ]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource[label=ownpubs]{ownpubs.bib}
\addbibresource[label=refs]{references.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \perdatasource{references.bib}
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={,Perhalo}, append]
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}

%here I want to print a selection of the complete bibliography
%References are required to be consistent throughout the whole document
\chapter*{Related Publications}
\printbibliography[heading=none,keyword={Perhalo}]

%here goes all the other stuff: chapters, sections, whatever

%print complete bibliography
\nocite{*} 
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, 'keyword' in combination with \refsection and \nocite solved it for me!